# Executing command line process as administrator using java

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

Have to install a custom service (Which requires administrative privilege) through runtime command line process using java.

OS Windows 7

Seems, that couldn't be done only with Java code but calling native commands through JNI.

The below code opens the command prompt as administrator but couldn't execute the subsequent command in the same prompt with the privilege.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start runas /user:domain\\administrator /savecred:try.txt cmd");
```

Is there any optimal way to achieve this?

thanks,

Comment: Have you tried running the java command from a Terminal run as administrator?

Comment: I would guess Windows since there is a dll tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a *nix system, you can use `sudo` from `Runtime.exec`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746869/how-to-generate-processes-with-inherited-rights-and-permissions/) for details.

Comment: Less known, but there is also `runas` on Windows.